# Deriving an expression using NSExpression

Tags: ios, swift, formula, nsexpression

I am stuck at a piece of code where I need to get the expression result based on the passed dictionary. For example:
expressionString = "(val1 + val2)"
How it is possible to pass these values from an dictionary or somewhere else. I searched many places but does't work for me.

```
let expressionString : String = "(val1 + val2)" as String
let expression = NSExpression(format: expressionString)
```

In above case I would like to know how I can map these val1 and val2 data by passing any argument.

Is it can be achieve by `let ex = NSExpression(format: expressionString, argumentArray:[parameter])`
?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931871/1187415 what you are looking for?

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855597/1187415 ?

Comment: Fine!, It helps me but I need to perform some changes at my end. No issue but sometime if the required values are not present in the passed argument then it will get crash, and we don't have ant option to handle the crash, does any one else faces the same issue..?

Comment: let expression = NSExpression(format: stringExpression!)
 let result = expression.expressionValue(with: variableDict, context: nil) as? NSNumber

Comment: NSExpression is quite limited in its functionality and error handling. But there are other expression parsers/evaluators, such as DDMathParser.